# Don't match if one and/OR two characters before the group contain specific text

Tags: regex

I want to match a group only if the group is not preceded by one OR two  certain characters.

I can get this working when there is just one preceding character.
But if I need to check for two preceding characters I'm stuck.

Example: 
I'm looking to match "2009-2010" as long as "2009-2010" is not preceded by "©" or "© "   (that's copyright sign + a space)

Example text: So here is your number to provide 2009-2010

Expected result: match 2009-2010

Example text:  All rights reserved © 2009-2010

Expected result: no match

My regex works for one preceding character such as: §@.©-

code: `(?<![§@.©-])\b(\d{4})-(\d{4})\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two negative lookbehinds, one to check for each situation:

```
(?<![§@.©-])(?<![§@.©-] )\b(\d{4})-(\d{4})\b
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/t7HH6y/2)

Comment: Problem with  (?<!© ) is that this prevents a match of any occurrence where "2009-2010" is preceded by space.

Comment: @user11662292 no it doesn't, it only prevents a match when `2009-2010` is preceded by a special character and a space. See the demo...

Comment: thank you!!    that does what I need it to do-- you rock

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sample with negative lookbehind for a group of characters starting with a section sign and can optionally have a space (The second question mark indicates that the character preceding it can or can not be present).

```
(?<!(©\s?))\b(\d{4}-\d{4})\b
```

If your requirement is to match different combinations of the character set in any order or length, use an asterisk after the closing square bracket to indicate that it can occur any number of times.

```
(?<![§@.©-]*)\b(\d{4})-(\d{4})\b
```

Comment: I used visual studio find option to verify these and it doesn't impose such a restriction. Not sure about other RegEx engines.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookbehind matching either one copyright character or a copyright character followed by a space.

Pattern: `(?<![§@.©-]|[§@.©-]\s)\b\d{4}-\d{4}\b`

[demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WGcdRs/5)

**Explanation**

- `(?<!` open a negative lookbehind

  - `[§@.©-]` either match the group of `[§@.©-]` symbols
  - `|` or
  - `[§@.©-]\s` match the group of `[§@.©-]` symbols followed by a `\s` space
- `)` close the negative lookbehind
- `\b` match a word boundary
- `d{4}-\d{4}` match 4 digits followed by a dash and another 4 digits
- `\b` ending word boundary

Comment: Only few regex engines support variable length lookbehind.